# Prompt a file to save -MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I want to prompt a save dialog to user.The file taype is .wav. The action is shown below

```
  public ActionResult MergeSelectedRecords(string mergeFileName, List<String> selectedRecords)
    {
       string urlFilePath=GetFilePath(); //get virtual path of file.       

       ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",        "attachment; filename=" + "cccc");    

       string filePath = ControllerContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(urlFilePath);
       return File(filePath, ".wav");
      }
```

A sampl file path is       'http:/localhost:2694/DATA/MERGE/OUT/1/cccc'

But it showing an error shown below

```
'http:/localhost:2694/DATA/MERGE/OUT/1/cccc' is not a valid virtual path.
```

Is this is a right way a to prompt a save file dialog to user?

**EDIT**

Sometimes there is no file availbale for user. So i only want to show an alert if the urlFilePath="".

IF no filepath is available How can i return an empty resul.And make an alert to user..The things i want is hown below

```
  public ActionResult MergeSelectedRecords(string mergeFileName, List<String> selectedRecords)
    {
       string urlFilePath=GetFilePath(); //get virtual path of file.       
     if(urlFilePath!="")
      {
       ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",        "attachment; filename=" + "cccc");    

       string filePath = ControllerContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(urlFilePath);
       return File(filePath, ".wav");
      }
     else
      {
           //what i return here? If it possible i only want to display an alert .But the page user viewing cannot refreshed
      } 
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `urlFilePath` argument that you are passing to the `MapPath` method must be a relative url within the same site starting with `~/`. Example:

```
public ActionResult MergeSelectedRecords(string mergeFileName, List<String> selectedRecords)
{
    string urlFilePath = "~/Files/ccc.wav";
    string filePath = Server.MapPath(urlFilePath);
    return File(filePath, ".wav", "ccc");
}
```

If the url is not part of your site you will need to download the file first. Example:

```
public ActionResult MergeSelectedRecords(string mergeFileName, List<String> selectedRecords)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        byte[] file = client.DownloadData("http://foo.com/ccc.wav");
        return File(file, ".wav", "ccc");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Darin.This is working. Thnx. But If i dont have file to return how can i return from action .(i want the the view that caused  for postback is not refreshed)

Comment: @Null Pointer, I don't understand your question. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @Null Pointer, now it's more clear. Well if a file is not found you could `throw new HttpException(404, "Not found")` which will send 404 or some other view to inform the user that the file doesn't exist.